# Screen freezes, mouse still works on Windows 7 - requires reboot

Tags: windows, freeze, windows-7

I started having super annoying problems on my machine all of a sudden (no hardware or software changes were made).

I can use the PC normally, and all of a sudden, the screen would just freeze, and stop responding to keyboard, and mouse clicks. Clock would freeze also. I can still move the mouse,  which changes from pointer, to hand, to stretch cursors when I move it over random stuff. Sometimes it would unfreeze after a minute or so, but usually it does not, and requires a power cycle.

Im running Windows 7 64x on i7 920, 12 GB ram, 2 x 80GB SSD raid0, dual 8800GTX, Gigabyte UDR5 mobo, 4 x 300GB drive in raid 5 on mobo, another 4 x 1.5TB in raid5 on a separate raid card and some 1000W power supply.

EDIT: Whats interesting is that once the screen freezes, computer still responds to mouse movements, and clicks, so if I move a mouse next a window, and resize it, it actually resizes it, but it doesn't visually change. The resize cursor position changes to where I last let it go. I can also minimize all windows, which doesn't allow me to resize anything anymore (since its all minimized), yet the screen still remains static. I figured this could be a GPU problem.... but why would the mouse still work?

Comment: Have a look at whether your box is running at a proper temperature on all the components, and testing your RAM won't hurt.

Comment: temps are high, but nothing crazy. CPU is at ~ 60. GPUs are like 85, but these are old 8800GTX, those run as hot as hell.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a display issue for sure.  Make sure your display drivers are up to date.  Try running the machine with the cover off to see if that changes when the freeze occurs; if it happens later or not at all, it's most likely heat related.  The temperatures you listed seem a trifle high by my standards.

Comment: Agreed: Update the display drivers from the manufacturer's site, not Windows Update.